# Show list items without metadata as ungrouped in SharePoint 2013 list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I can't find information on this anywhere, but in my head it should absolutely be possible.

I have a list where 90% of the list items have metadata, and grouped accordingly. There are however some items without any metadata that I want to be shown as single list items, i.e. not grouped under "Metadata:(none)"

My case is shown in the following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxeeN.png), where in order to view the "0 - Inspection Management Process" and "RBI Update", I have to open the "Main System:(2)", and "Parent System:(2)".

Is there anyway to sort of "push" these items forward, so that there is not need to open groups to show them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could filter them out of the view and add a second web part below that shows only these ungrouped items by using a second filter.  But when you have grouped a view it groups all items.